# Is ESA's ExoMars TGA getting old and unable to support Rosalind Franklin rover for the full potential duration of its missions and extensions?

Tags: mars, planetary-science, rovers, exomars, trace-gas-orbiter

Wikipedia's [ExoMars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExoMars) explains that the [Trace Gas Orbiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_Gas_Orbiter) or TGO part of the mission was launched in 2016 and the rover was originally scheduled to launch in 2018. This launch was delayed until 2020 and now has been delayed again until 2022.

**Question:** Do these delays impact the level of support that TGO can provide? Is anything on it getting old or wearing out, or will it still be 100% ready to support the rover once it gets there, for the full *potential* duration of its missions and any extensions<sup>1</sup>?

<sup>1</sup>Deep space missions often have short stated initial mission durations but are actually built to possibly last much longer; Extreme examples include

1. [Opportunity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_(rover))'s 15 years versus its planned 90 days driving around Mars
2. [International Sun-Earth Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Cometary_Explorer) or ISEE-3 with its second mission as the International *Cometary* Explorer or ICE, and then its citizen-science reboot that together span from 1978 until 2014!

Comment: [Rosalind Franklin is no longer called "ExoMars rover", how to manage tags and titles of older questions?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1193/12102)